# @autowire beans and @value properties after object mapper deserialized json

Tags: spring, jackson, autowired, objectmapper

I am using spring framework.

I am using objectMapper to desiriale store.json file:

service:

```
objectMapper.readValue(new File(jsonFilePath), Store.class)
```

store.json:

```
{
  "type": "Store",
  "name": "myStore",
}
```

Store.class:

```
@Value("${store.size:1000}")
private Integer sroreSize;

@autowire
private storePersistency storePersistency;

public Store(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

I am trying find out how to @autowire beans and @value properties in store.class, beans and properties that exist in applicationContext. 
In current example sroreSize and storePersistency still null.

I know that I can inject fields to object mapper and then use @JacksonInject annotation but I have a lot of field to inject - not a good option for me.
Custom desirializer also not a good option for me.

Is there any way not to use custom desirializer or not to inject every bean/property that I need in store.class? 
Something that injects all the beans and properties and I simply can use it in Store.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want some `Store` fields like `storePersistency` and `sroreSize` to be initialized once at application startup (which is when Spring will setup the application context) and then at runtime create multiple different `Store` objects differing in some fields as `name` that are initialized by Jackson.

I suggest annotating `Store` with `@Component` to get Spring to initialize `@Value` and `@Autowired` fields. The [@Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) annotation will cause a new independent `Store` instance to be created each time. Simplified example:

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class Store {

    private String name;

    @Value("${store.size:1000}")
    private Integer sroreSize;
}
```

Then the key is method [readerForUpdating](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating-java.lang.Object-) where you can pass an existing instance of `Store` and Jackson will update that instead of creating a new one as usually:

```
    Store store = context.getBean(Store.class);
    objectMapper.readerForUpdating(store).readValue("{\"name\":\"myStore\"}");
```

Where `context` is a Spring [ApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) reference that I autowired in a test class. You don't need to use the return value of `readValue` in this case, just inspect the existing `store` variable and `name` will be updated.